# type mismatch while assigning value to object while using variables as keys

Tags: typescript

Consider this example where I have an `myType` which has 2 props with different types. When I loop over a set of keys of `myType` and use said keys to assign values from one object to another (both objects being of type `myType`), the assignment shows a Type error.

> Type '{ x: number; } | { x: { foo: number; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ x: number; } & { x: { foo: number; }; }'.

How does the type inference work here? shouldn't the value of `oldObject[key]` be inferred as `{ x: number; } | { x: { foo: number; }; }` and not with an `&`?

```js
type myType = {
    a: {x: number}
    b: {x: {foo: number}}
}

const oldObject: myType = {
    a: {x: 3},
    b: {x: {foo: 3}}
};

const newObject: myType  = {
    a: {x: 4},
    b: {x: {foo: 4}}
};

(['a', 'b'] as Array<keyof myType>).forEach(key => {
    
    // assignment
    oldObject[key] = newObject[key]; // Type error here

})
```